# How can i host my django project on my computer and access it from anywhere in the world?

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to make my computer as a host for my django project and I can access my django project from anywhere in the world?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy your Django apps in your Computer and forward your port to access from the internet. You will need a fixed IP though.

Here is a read for you.[How To Deploy a Django App To apache2 Server On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop](https://quicknotepadtutorial.blogspot.com/2020/04/how-to-deploy-django-app-to-apache2.html)